# How to use, $(|u|^{2}u - |v|^{2}v)(s)= (u-v)|u|^{2}(s)+ v(|u|^{2}-|v|^{2}) (s)$; to prove contraction in a Banach space $C([0,T]; M^{p,1})$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

(May be this is very basic question for MO)

(For details or this question  you may see the [paper page no. 9](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.0833.pdf), MR2506839, Local well-posedness of nonlinear dispersive equations on modulation spaces; Bull. Lond. Math. Soc. 41 (2009), no. 3, 549-558)

Let $u_{0}$ be in the  [modulation space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulation_space) $M^{p,1}(\mathbb R^{d})= M^{p,1}, \ (1\leq p < \infty).$

***Theorem 1***. If $u_{0}\in M^{p,1}$ then $||e^{it\bigtriangleup}u_{0}||_{M^{p,1}}\leq C (t^{2}+4\pi^{2})^{\frac{d}{4}} ||u_{0}||_{M^{p,1}},$ where $C$ is universal constant depending only on  $d$. Therefore, $||e^{it\bigtriangleup}||_{M^{p,1}(\mathbb R^{d})}\leq C_{T} ||u_{0}||_{M^{p,1}(\mathbb R^{d})},$ where $C_{T}= \sup_{t\in [0, T)} C(t^{2}+ 4\pi^{2})^{d/4}.$
Consider the mapping,
$$\mathcal{T}(u)=e^{it\bigtriangleup}(u_{0})-i \int_{0}^{t}e^{i(t-s)\bigtriangleup}( |u|^{2}u) (s) ds.$$
Let $B_{M}$ denote the closed ball of radius $M=2C_{T}\left\|u_{0}\right\|_{M^{p,1}}$ , centred at the origin in the space $C([0, T]; M^{p,1}).$

***Theorem 2***. If $u\in M^{p,1}$, then $\left\||u|^{2k}u \right\|_{M^{p,1}}\lesssim\left\|u\right \|_{M^{p,1}}^{2k+1}.$

By using, theorem 1 and theorem 2, we notice, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left \|\int_{0}^{t}e^{i(t-s)\bigtriangleup}(\lambda |u|^{2k}u)(s)ds \right \|_{M^{p,1}} &\leq & \int_{0}^{t}||e^{i(t-s)\bigtriangleup}(\lambda |u|^{2k}u)(s) ||_{M^{p,1}} ds\\
&\leq & T C_{T} \sup_{t\in [0, T]} \left \|\lambda |u|^{2k}u \right\|_{M^{p,1} (\mathbb R^{d})}\\
& \lesssim  &  C_{T} T \left \| u(t)\right \|_{M^{p,1}}^{2k+1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So,$\left\|\mathcal{T}(u) \right \|_{C([0, T]; M^{p,1})}\leq C_{T}(||u_{0}||_{M^{p,1}}+cT ||u||^{2k+1}_{M^{p,1}}),$ for some universal positive constant $c$. 
Let $u\in B_{M}$, we obtain,$\left\|T(u)\right \|_{C([0, T]; M^{p,1})} \leq \frac{M}{2}+cC_{T}T M^{2k+1}.$ Now, let $T$ be such that $cC_{T}M^{2k} \leq \frac{1}{2},$ that is, $T\leq \tilde{T}(||u_{0}||_{M^{p,1}}).$ We obtain, $\mathcal{T}(u) \in B_{M},$ and so  $\mathcal{T}:B_{M}\to B_{M}.$

> ***My Question***: How to prove
>   $$\left\|\mathcal {T}(u)-\mathcal {T} (v) \right \|_{C([0, T]; M^{p,1})}\leq \frac{1}{2}\left\|u-v\right \|_{C([0, T]; M^{p,1})} ? $$

The [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.0833.pdf) (p.9) I have been reading gives hint that one can use this identity, $(|u|^{2}u -  |v|^{2}v)(s)= (u-v)|u|^{2}(s)+ v(|u|^{2}-|v|^{2}) (s)$; to prove the contraction, but I am unable to see, and  I am wondering how such identity will be useful ? or may be some different method is available ?)

Any suggestions or comments or any reference  will be helpful to me; thanks a lot;

Comment: You also need a version of Theorem 2.1 for the product of two functions. This kind of extension is usually obtained through minor modifications in the proof of the case of a single power

Comment: @PD; what is known so far is; $||uv||_{M^{p,1}}\leq ||u||_{M^{p,1}} ||v||_{M^{p,1}}$ for $u,v \in M^{p,1}$; that is $M^{p,1}$ is an Banach algebra.; thanks for the attention; but I don't see how this is useful?

Comment: Look at Formula (12) page 8 of the first paper you mention.

Comment: @AW; For $\frac{1}{p_{1}}+...+\frac{1}{p_{m}}=\frac{1}{p_{0}}$ and $\frac{1}{q_{1}}+...+\frac{1}{q_{m}} =m-1+\frac{1}{q_{0}},$; then $||u_{1}\cdot\cdot\cdot u_{m}||_{M^{p_{0},q_{0}}}\leq ||u_{1}||_{M^{p_{1},q_{1}}}\cdot \cdot \cdot ||u_{m}||_{M^{p_{m}, q_{m}}}$; but how this will be  useful here ?

Comment: So \begin{eqnarray*}
&&\left \|\int_{0}^{t}e^{i(t-s)\bigtriangleup}(\lambda |u|^{2k}u-\lambda |v|^{2k}v)(s)ds \right \|_{M^{p,1}} \\
&\leq & 
T C_{T} \sup_{t\in [0, T]} \left \|\lambda |u|^{2k}u-\lambda |v|^{2k}v  \right\|_{M^{p,1}}\\
&\leq & T C_{T} \sup_{t\in [0, T]} \left \|\lambda |u|^{2k}(u-v)\right\|_{M^{p,1}}\\
&&+T C_{T} \sup_{t\in [0, T]} \left \|\lambda (|v|^{2k}-|v|^{2k})v \right\|_{M^{p,1} (\mathbb R^{d})}\\
& \lesssim  &  C_{T} T  \left(\|u\|^{2k}_{M^{p,1}}+\|u\|^{2k-2}_{M^{p,1}} \|v\|_{M^{p,1}}+\|v\|_{M^{p,1}}^{2k}\right)\|u-v\|_{M^{p,1}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @AW;thanks a lot; I am wondering, how did you manage to get $\|u-v\|$ is multiple of just three terms; that means, is it true that number of terms is independent of $k$ ? [ It is clear to me that, $|u|^{2k}u-|v|^{2k}v= (u-v)|u|^{2k}+v(|u|^{2k}-|v|^{2k})$ = $ (u-v)|u|^{2k}+v(u^{k}\bar{u}^{k}-v^{k}\bar{u}^{k}+v^{k}\bar{u}^{k}-\bar{v}^{k});$            then applying norm, and noticing in this space $\bar{u}$ preserves   norm,  I got, terms multiple of $\|u-v\|$; but number of terms depends on $k$; but I wants know, how you manage to get $\|u-v\|$ multiple of just three terms ? Thanks again;